# Angular importing JS file/SDK not a module

Tags: javascript, angular, avaya

So i am using the Avaya SDK (basically 3 JS files) in my Angular project. When i try to import it i get an error saying that it is not a module? Any idea how to fix that?

my import statement:

```
import * as AvayaClientServices from '../../../assets/lib/AvayaClientServices.min.js';

declare const AvayaClientServices: any
```

There is btw no "export" in the JS File so i dont know if thats the issue? The whole file has li 30k Lines of Code so here is the beginning:

```
! function(T) {
var S = jQuery;
! function(e) {
    "use strict";

    function i(e) {
        this.clientConfiguration = e, this.user = T, this.mediaServicesFactory = T, this.version = "4.8.0.37", i.Base.Logger.clearLoggers()
    }
    i.prototype = {
        createUser: function(e) {
            return this.user || (this.mediaServicesFactory === T && (this.mediaServicesFactory = new i.Base.MediaServicesFactory), i.SDK_VERSION = this.version, this.user = new i.User(e, this.mediaServicesFactory, this.version)), this.user
        },
        registerLogger: function(e, t) {
            i.Base.Logger.addLogger(e, t)
        },
        getMediaServices: function() {
            return this.mediaServicesFactory === T && (this.mediaServicesFactory = new i.Base.MediaServicesFactory), this.mediaServicesFactory.getMediaServices()
        },
        getVersion: function() {
            return this.version
        }
    }, e.AvayaClientServices = i
```

Answer (score 0):

`Modules` are a mechanism that `JavaScript` `runtime` supports to allow the split of huge chunks of code into small reusable pieces that you can use (`import`) in other programs.

The above error is due to missing `export` keyword from `source-file`. The `runtime` failed to identify what you are pointing to during the interpretation of the reference statement.

As stated in `MDN` [right here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#a_background_on_modules)

> Use of native JavaScript modules is dependent on the import and export
> statements;

Comment: okay i see, but how should i "import" the SDK without an import statement? When using @ts-ignore above the import i dont get an error (obviously) and i can somehow reference Methods from the AvayaClient SDK and command + clicking the method redirects me to the Avaya JS File, so i assumed it would work. But then i get other erros like "i.User is not a constructor" or something like that while using Methods from the JS file